# How to extract the dynamically generated HTML from a website

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

Is it possible to extract the HTML of a page as it shows in the HTML panel of Firebug or the Chrome DevTools?

I have to crawl a lot of websites but sometimes the information is not in the static source code, a JavaScript runs after the page is loaded and creates some new HTML content dynamically. If I then extract the source code, these contents are not there.

I have a web crawler built in Java to do this, but it's using a lot of old libraries. Therefore, I want to move to a Rails/Ruby solution for learning purposes. I already played a bit with [Nokogir](http://nokogiri.org/)i and [Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crawler is able to execute JavaScript, you can simply get the dynamically created HTML structure using `document.firstElementChild.outerHTML`.

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and [Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) are currently **not** able to parse JavaScript. See
"[Ruby Nokogiri Javascript Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461931/ruby-nokogiri-javascript-parsing)" and "[How do I use Mechanize to process JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript)" for this.

You will need another tool like [WATIR](http://watir.com/) or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). Those drive a real web browser, and can thus handle any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch the records coming from the database side. You can only fetch the HTML code which is static.

JavaScript must be requesting the records from the database using a query request which can't be fetch by the crawler.

Comment: Even the Javascript that is inside the HTML?, the data is inside the HTML just in the <script type="text/javascript"> tags

Comment: What does this javascript will do..? is it fetching records from database..? and one more question that is your crawler is able to fetch javascript code ..?

Comment: Look at this example: http://loja.puket.com.br/pijamas/feminino-adulto/pijama/conjunto-longo-coruja-030600572 its a Brazilian website, so just look at the dropdown named "Tamanho", as you can see theres 3 sizes you can choose, if you look at them with the inspector tool you can actually see them inside <option> but in the HTML they appear as a json inside a <script> tag.

Comment: The question and JavaScript execution are unrelated to databases.